# JSDoc type for returned class instances

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, es6-modules, jsdoc3

I'm using Node.js with two modules and one script that depends on them:

**lib/Bar.js**

```
module.exports = class Bar {
  // ..
};
```

**lib/Foo.js**

```
const Bar = require('./Bar.js');

module.exports = class Foo {
  /**
   * @return {Bar} A Bar instance
  */
  get someBar() {
    return new Bar();
  }
};
```

**main.js**

```
const Foo = require('./lib/Foo.js');

checkFoo(new Foo());

/**
 * @param {Foo} foo A Foo instance
*/
function checkFoo(foo) {
  foo. // I get suggestions for Foo properties
  foo.someBar. // I get suggestions for Bar properties

  checkBar(foo.someBar);
}

/**
 * @param {Bar} bar a Bar instance
*/
function checkBar(bar) {
  bar. // I get no suggestions!
}
```

My code editor Visual Studio Code uses IntelliSense to give the user suggestions about Foo and Bar properties, which works correctly inside the `checkFoo` method as the type of `foo` is declared as `Foo` object, and the type of `foo.someBar` is declared in the `Foo` class as a `Bar` object.

But as soon as I pass this `Bar` instance to another method (`checkBar`), the type `Bar` isn't recognized (probably because I don't require the module). **Is there a special syntax in JSDoc to specify a type as being declared in another module?** Or is this just an issue with VSCode?

Comment: Does this help http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html ?

Comment: @Lazyexpert Unfortunately, not. All properties in Bar are documented with valid JSDoc comments and as suggestions were shown in the `checkFoo` method, the reference does work. I only wonder how to get the suggestions working in `checkBar`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You no longer need to import the type (which may break linters, for instance). Instead, you can hint VSCode (actually, TypeScript) by using the import type syntax:

```
const Foo = require('./lib/Foo.js');

...

/**
 * @param {import('./lib/Bar.js').default} bar a Bar instance
 */
function checkBar(bar) {
    ...
}
```

*Note that the keyword default is only required because it's a default export.*

Comment: Thanks, that's something I was looking for. Just to add that you don't need `.default` with CommonJS modules (like in the example in my question). However, this approach doesn't work in VSCode with `.mjs` files yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your suspicion is correct. Currently, you also need to import `Bar` to use its type in the jsdoc:

```
const Foo = require('./lib/Foo.js');
const Bar = require('./lib/Bar.js');

...

/**
 * @param {Bar} bar a Bar instance
 */
function checkBar(bar) {
    ...
}
```

We are tracking support for a JSDoc equivalent of `require` or `import` here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377